# Overriding Scaffold Controller in Rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Briefly, I want to override and/or add additional files when running `rails generate scaffold MyModel name:string` for example.

1. [DONE] Override the views
2. [????] Override the controller.rb
3. [????] Add to the views such as `destroy.turbo_stream.haml`, `_mymodel.html.haml`

I've spent the afternoon reading documentation reading how to override templates with rails generators at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#overriding-rails-generator-templates along with a slew of posts on how to over-ride various parts of controllers.

While I was able to override some of the views, I've yet been able find the path magic to override the `controller.rb` used during scaffold generation.

Per this, I should be able to add the controller file somewhere in `lib/templates` but nothing is working.

I wanted to add `before_action :authenticate_user!` and some other changes that I want to ensure are always in scaffolded controllers.

Any thoughts as to the specific location within railties ... per documentation it is this: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt

But then where in `lib/` does it go?

- I've tried `lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt`
- I've tried `lib/templates/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt`
- I've tried `lib/templates/controller.rb.tt`
- I've tried ... banging my head

I'd love some help.  HELP!! :)

P.S.  And if you know how to add additional views (e.g. `destroy.turbo_stream.haml` to the mix in the views along with `_MODEL.html.haml` I'd love to figure that out, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Override the views

*https://github.com/haml/haml-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates*

```rb
# lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates/show.html.haml
#             .--'    |                  |
#             |    .--'     .------------'
#             v    v        v
lib/templates/haml/scaffold/show.html.haml
```

```bash
$ bin/rails g scaffold Testing
...
$ cat app/views/testings/show.html.haml
hi haml
```

---

> Override the controller.rb

Override default controller template from railties gem:

```rb
# lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt
#             .--------'     |                             |
#             |     .--------'          .------------------'
#             v     v                   v
lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb.tt
```

---

> Add to the views such as `destroy.turbo_stream.haml`.

Generate a generator in *rails* namespace:

```bash
$ bin/rails g generator rails/my_scaffold
```

```rb
# lib/generators/rails/my_scaffold/my_scaffold_generator.rb

class Rails::MyScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  # run default scaffold
  invoke "scaffold_controller"

  # add new stuff
  include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers
  source_root File.expand_path("templates", __dir__)
  def copy_view_files
    ["destroy.turbo_stream.haml"].each do |filename|
      template filename, File.join("app/views", controller_file_path, filename)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/generators/rails/my_scaffold/templates/destroy.turbo_stream.haml.tt

# TODO: make a template
```

Change default scaffold controller generator:

```rb
# config/application.rb

config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_controller :my_scaffold
end
```

```
$ bin/rails g scaffold Testing   
...
     create    app/views/testings/destroy.turbo_stream.haml
```

---

You could get a bit more granular if you want:

```rb
# config/application.rb

config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :my_scaffold
end
```

and then instead of invoking the whole scaffold just `invoke "haml:scaffold"` the rest is the same.

---

This isn't the prettiest way of adding to the scaffold, because the scaffold log is nested under my_scaffold. If you want to add this generator to be invoked by the scaffold instead, you'll have to add a new hook:

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Base.html#method-c-hook_for*

For example, have a look at how jbuilder does it:
*https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/v2.11.5/lib/jbuilder/railtie.rb#L29*
*https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/tree/v2.11.5/lib/generators/rails*

Comment: Just wanted to acknowledge this; I will report back if I run into issues.  I appreciate the very thorough response.

Comment: really appreciate this!   This really helped me solved a sore spot.  I'm finding that I cannot override `haml-rails` so I'm going to likely just over-write them entirely or overload the `:haml` generator for my purposes.  That said, I think I'm unblocked.

Let me know if you have a tip jar. ;)

Comment: @WardW.Vuillemot you mean override the view templates? it should be `lib/templates/haml/scaffold/show.html.haml` etc. https://github.com/haml/haml-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates

Answer (score 1):

For sake of adding some more texture to answer from Alex which 100% nailed my questions.

I wanted to added a partial view such as `app/views/my_models/_my_model.html` which is populated with the model attributes and values.

Out of the box, the above example from Alex ended up crapping out till I stumbled upon https://garrettdimon.com/journal/posts/creating-custom-rails-generators, see Figure 13 for specifics.

This resulted in some minor tweaks, or:

`# lib/generators/rails/my_scaffold/my_scaffold_generator.rb`

```
class Rails::MyScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
   # run default scaffold
  invoke 'scaffold_controller'
  argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], 
    banner: "field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]"

  # add new stuff
  include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers
  source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
  def copy_view_files
    ['destroy.turbo_stream.haml'].each do |filename|
      template filename, File.join('app/views', controller_file_path, filename)
    end
    ['partial.html.haml'].each do |filename|
      template filename, File.join('app/views', controller_file_path, "_#{singular_table_name}.html.haml")
    end
  end

end
```

More specifically, two things I added are:

```
    argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], 
    banner: "field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]"
```

which ensures you can access model attributes in the template.

```
    ['partial.html.haml'].each do |filename|
      template filename, File.join('app/views', controller_file_path, "_#{singular_table_name}.html.haml")
    end
```

adds a partial and renames it to the singular model name

And then I added to my generator templates:

`# lib/generators/rails/my_scaffold/templates/partial.html.haml.tt`

```
.container
<%- attributes.each do |attribute| -%>
    %p
        %b <%= attribute.name.humanize %>:
        =<%= singular_table_name %>.<%= attribute.name %>
<%- end -%>

    = link_to 'Edit', edit_<%= singular_table_name %>_path(<%= singular_table_name %>), class: 'btn btn-secondary m-1'
```

**Note**, I did not find the `.tt` entirely necessary since I'm using `haml` vs `erb` as `tt` is itself a variant of `tt`, or so I understand.

And that, coupled to Alex's answer above ensures

1. Ability to override the default controller
2. Ability to override the default views
3. Ability to add new views

Comment: `.tt` would be needed if you were to use a `directory` command instead of the whole "each template": `directory ".", File.join("app/views", controller_file_path`